# Nginx thousands of connections

Tags: nginx

I have a server with an nginx server (1.10.2), since we migrated a few dozens websites on it it keeps "crashing". It's still up, but it just doesn't answer any requests or log anything until a reload or a restart is done.

Looking at the status page just after a reload :

```
Active connections: 9432 
server accepts handled requests
 550310 550310 657656 
Reading: 0 Writing: 3280 Waiting: 6150
```

That seems ridiculous, and looking at the access logs there aren't enough queries to justify that. Wondering if it might be something like a slowris attack, I tried lowering client_body_timeout and client_header_timeout to 5s, it looks like it's climbing slower now but who knows.
Any ideas what I could do to prevent that nginx from dying every few hours ?

I already disabled keepalive, just in case, didn't change a thing.

EDIT : The nginx.conf :

```
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
user www-data;
worker_processes 12;
worker_rlimit_nofile 300000;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
events
{
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
    worker_connections 2048;
}

http
{
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    server_tokens off;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    client_max_body_size 100M;
    keepalive_timeout 0;

    gzip on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    gzip_types
        text/plain
        text/css
        text/js
        text/xml
        text/javascript
        application/javascript
        application/x-javascript
        application/json
        application/xml
        application/rss+xml
        image/svg+xml
        font/opentype
        image/gif
        image/jpeg
        image/png      
        image/bmp
        image/x-icon;
}
```

And one of the sites :

```
server
{
    listen              80;

    root                /home/sitename/www;

    server_name             sitename.com;

    access_log              /var/log/nginx/sitename_access.log;
    error_log               /var/log/nginx/sitename_error.log;

    pagespeed                           on;
    pagespeed                           FileCachePath "/tmp/pagespeed/sitename";

    include                             "pagespeed.conf";

    if ($host != 'www.sitename.com')
    {
      return 301 $scheme://www.sitename.com$request_uri;
    }

    location /
    {
        index                           index.php index.html index.htm;
        try_files                       $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$
    {
        fastcgi_pass            fastcgi_sitename;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        include                 fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

pagespeed.conf is only a bunch of filters. Some sites have a few other location blocs, some have https, but nothing I haven't done on hundreds of other productions servers without any problems.

Comment: Without further information on your setup, my guess is that your application server is too slow with processing the requests passed to it, and even a little traffic can make it use all the connections available in nginx. You need to study your application.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but of course the problem isn't ressources, the server is barely doing anything when that happens. Not more than 2 of load avg, spare ram ...

Comment: The fact that there is not any load showing does not mean that it couldn't be the application.

Comment: Use `watch -d --no-title -n4 'netstat -s | egrep -i "lock|socket\ buf"'` when this is occuring and see if locked socket increases.  If so, your apps or backend webservers are not keeping up with the request rate.

Comment: Both number are high (10982 delayed and 893 bad SACK) but they don't look like they increase no, at least not right now.

Answer (score 2):

You probably hit max connections limit (worker_processes * worker_connections). When you reload nginx, it spawns new processes and let old ones finish requests and die.  Therefore your connections limit gets reset.

Try to check netstat where the connections come from:

```
netstat -t -n -v | grep ESTABLISHED
```

<s>You can then try to set client timeouts:</s>

- <s>http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_body_timeout</s>
- <s>http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_header_timeout</s>

Looking at your server status, I can see 2 important things:

- Writing: 3280 (The current number of connections where nginx is writing the response back to the client.)
- Waiting: 6150 (The current number of idle client connections waiting for a request.)

So you have 3280 clients receiving response from your webserver and 6150 clients doing nothing - perhaps keepalive?

Access log is filled only when a request finishes. If you have 3000 clients waiting for response, you will not see them in the access log until they receive whole response. However you can workaround this problem by writing a small lua script, which you call via access_by_lua.

You can also tune your access log and log processing time of your application via $request_time. Please check documentation for more variables: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format

Comment: As mentionned, I already turned keepalive off, and it's not one application, it's a bunch of different websites. Also netstat definitly doesn't have 3000 IPs int it, I checked, there's less than a 1000 lines in there when there is 9000 active connections in nginx

Comment: As for the max worker, that was the problem at first, but I bumped it to 2048 and nginx hasn't complained about it since. I also had to increase the max file open. Since that the error.log doesn't show anything when the "crash" happens

Comment: Update your original post with your nginx configuration. Also add: "netstat -t -n -v | awk '{print $6}' | sort -n | uniq -c" and current server-status when you execute that command. I have never seen nginx to missbehave like this.

Comment: Right now I have 910 connections in nginx according to the status, the netstat command returns 622 TIME_WAIT and about ~20 connections in other states

Comment: Does a TIME_WAIT in netstat count as an active connection in nginx ? If yes, I guess the problem is a gif on one of the site that gets included in a lot of other sites, resulting in hundreds of connection per minute. It doesn't generate any load, as it's just an image, but I guess it generates a lot of connections that stay around for a couple of minute due to the way TIME_WAIT works, and in peak hour I guess that's enough to saturate the max open connections on the server ?

Comment: TIME_WAIT shouldn't be problem. Could you please pass nginx configuration? Without understanding what your setup is like I am not sure if we can help.

Comment: Well, which part ? There is more than 400 .conf file in there, can't really paste it all here. I'm putting the main nginx.conf in my original post

Comment: This seems ok. Would you mind sharing conf.d/*.conf and one of your sites-enabled config? I suppose all of them are the same and you only change domain name. Right?

Comment: conf.d just contains a fastcgi bloc for each fpm pool, one per site.

Comment: Ok. do you have your own build of nginx? There can be some problem with one of the modules. There are 2 things, I'd try. Firstly I would install dotdeb/official nginx package and disabled modules that are not needed. Secondly I would enable debug mode and went through a tons of logs to findout what is happening there. If there is something wrong, it should be visible very quickly.

Comment: That's actually the nginx-extras package from dotdeb, nothing custom about that. We do have our custom build of PHP, but I don't think that's related. As for the debug logs, I'll try that tomorrow then, any clues on what I should be looking for ? I've never read nginx's debug logs yet

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out where the problem is coming from, I disabled pagespeed for the week end and no problem since.
According to the logs pagespeed is requesting nginx itself A LOT.

Looking at the doc it seems like I could prevent that by using LoadFromFile, so I guess I'll experiment with that and try to find some config that works without bringing down the server ..